# How does Hibernate control the transaction with multiple session.update()s if you don't commit the transaction explicitly?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, db2, database-deadlocks

I have inherited a system that uses Spring MVC and Hibernate that stores into a DB2 database. Recently it started having what looks like a deadlock problem reported by DB2 so I've been working on debugging it. I'm not a Spring or Hibernate expert but I know some of both.

The code is structured like this:

```
controller -> service -> one or more DAO classes that performs the updates
```

In the situation where the problem occurs the controller calls a service method annotated with `@Transactional` and `@Override`. The service goes to a DAO class annotated with `@Repository` and calls multiple methods annotated with `@Transactional` and `@Override`. That is the structure of code.

One controller calls one service method. The service method calls multiple DAO methods. Most of the DAO methods are marked `@Transactional` and `@Override`.  A few have REQUIRES_NEW in the `@Transactional`.  Also in each DAO method the `Session` is gotten by `SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`.

First question: with this approach where does the transaction start and where is the ultimate commit? And the rollback? None of this is explicitly coded.

The deadlock comes when one of the methods updates a record and then a subsequent method deletes that same record. If you are wondering why anyone wants to do this the update adds the user id of the person wanting to delete the information in the record so that it can be saved by a stored process to another table. Then the second method call deletes the record.

The original coder tried adding REQUIRES_NEW to the `@Transactional` thinking a new transaction would ensure the update would happen. But the deadlock still happens at irregular intervals.

I tried changing the update to a native SQL call but Hibernate won't let me start another transaction since one is already open.

Anyone have any guidance here?

Comment: Edited my original post to answer your question.

Comment: Yes, I did find that Hibernate would ignore the update I am assuming because it saw that the record was going to be deleted but I didn't want that because after updating the record something like a stored process (in this case DB2's temporal table system) is copying the record to a history table. What is ultimately happening is that Hibernate is attempting to first update a record (which causes DB2 to copy that record to another table) and then deleting that record.  So three database operations are being attempted on the same record and I bet that is causing the deadlock.

Comment: Deadlock is when two transactions are waiting on each other to give up locks.

Answer (score 1):

The transaction starts when a method (which class or the method itself firstly annotated with `@Transactional` in the call chain) called from outside (it must call from outside of the class, because the annotation "creates" a proxy). Any other annotated class/methods in the chain with default propagation level will join to that transaction. When call a method with transactional marked as `REQUIRES_NEW`, the parent transaction will be suspended (if exists) and the new transaction starts. Note that if you call annotated method from other method in the same class, then it wont go throught the proxy, so it same as you delete the annotation. The commit happened right after the method who start the transaction return. Same as rollback, it will after exception is thrown. Deadlock can come from different places, it is hard to find out, even if you have code. It can for example come from update and stored procedure try to lock some rows and cyclic waiting happend etc...

I have a naive image, what happen in the background.
There are two class ui and service. The service is annotated as `@Transactional`.
Spring create the proxy, and all calls come from outside go through it. Before the real method will be called, it start the transaction, after that it will commit.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining how this works. Now I know the transaction boundaries at least. I'm thinking that my deadlock problem comes from the stored procedure trying to access the same table record at the same time as the code that tries to delete it.